# SublimeREPL (SublimeText 3) interactive mode settings

Tags: sublime-text-plugin

I have manage to install and use sublimeREPL in sublimetext3, setting an new build system

My only problem is that I can not set SublimeREPL to interactive mode so I can give inputs through sublimetext3 shell.

I tried to edit the string setting "-i" but not worked.

Any idea how to set up this? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Solved,
I used "i" instead of "-i" to make sublimeREPL interactive.
Everything is ok now.